# Why I can "<:" on the type class declaration but could not use "<:<"

Tags: scala

The following code compile successfully, but the second couldn't compile. As my understanding these 2 symbols both mean type constraint.

```
class Hello[T <: String](t:T)

class Hello[T <:< String](t:T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are a little different. `<:` is a type constraint meaning `A` is subtype of `B`, while `<:<` is a type meaning the same thing. So this would work:

```
class Hello[T <: String](t:T)

class Hello[T](t: T <:< String)
```

alternative

```
class Hello[T](t: <:<[T, String])
```

edit:

One use case would be to prove, that one type param is a subtype of the other:

```
def foo[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A <:< B) = "yay"

scala> foo(Nil, List(1,2,3))
res13: java.lang.String = yay

scala> foo(List(1,2,3), Nil)
<console>:9: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type.
              foo(List(1,2,3), Nil)
                 ^
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this? I understand <:, but I don't understand what you mean by 'meaning the same thing'. When would I use <:< as opposed to <:?

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear to think of <:<[A, B] as a type, whose values are proofs that A is subtype of B. Also see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$$less$colon$less.html This is small incarnation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence in scala.